What is the chance of two events happening after X attemps?
Let's say two favorable events have a 5% and a 10% chance of happening. Each time you try, you can only get one favorable event. How would you then calculate the probability that both events happened after you tried X times?
I know that for one favorable event that chance is, by newton's binominal law, 1 - 0.95^x. But how to include both?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

They are disjoint (you can only get one, with probabilities $0.05$ and $0.1$), so the chance of neither of them happening is $1 - 0.05 - 0.1 = 0.85$.

The probability of neither of them happening after $X$ attempts is $0.85^X$.

The probability of event $1$ not happening after $X$ attempts is $(1-0.05)^X = 0.95^X$ .

The probability of event $2$ not happening after $X$ attempts is $(1-0.1)^X = 0.9^X$.


We can use these $3$ and the inclusion-exclusion principle to compute our desired probability.

We get that the probability of both happening is $1-0.9^x - 0.95^x + 0. 85^x$ :


Let $a=0.05$ and $b=0.1$ denote the probability of each of the two events.
The likelihood that after $n$ trials, the first event has not occurred is $(1-a)^n$.
The likelihood that the second event has not occurred is $(1-b)^n$.
The likelihood that neither event has occurred is $(1-a-b)^n$.
This allows us to compute the likelihood of any combination of each even either occurring not not, including the likelihood that both events have happened:
$$1-(1-a)^n-(1-b)^n+(1-a-b)^n$$
In this case, you can compute the combinations by hand. In general, this follows the inclusion-exclusion principle.
